# How to call a function inside SpookyJS?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs, spookyjs

I have a function called `clickMore`:

```
function clickMore(max, i){
   i = i || 0;
   if ((max == null || i < max) && this.visible(moreButton)) { // synchronous
      // asynchronous steps...
      this.thenClick(moreButton);  // sometimes the click is not properly dispatched
      this.echo('click');
      this.waitUntilVisible(loadingButton);
      this.waitUntilVisible(moreButton, null, function onTimeout(){
         // only placeholder so that the script doesn't "die" here if the end is reached
      });
      this.then(function(){

         //this.capture("business_"+i+".png");   //captures a screenshot of the page
         clickMore.call(this, max, i+1); // recursion
      });
   }
}
```

I would like to call that function from spooky here:

```
spooky.then(function(){
              clickMore.call(spooky);
          })
```

I've looked through the Spooky docs, and know that I'll probably need to use a function tuple, but not sure how to implement. How can I go about doing this?

**UPDATE:**

Tried using a function tuple from the SpookyJS documentation with no luck:

```
spooky.then([{
   clickMore: clickMore
}, function(){
    clickMore.call(spooky);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions passed into `spooky.then` will execute in the Casper/PhantomJS JavaScript environment. They do not have access to Spooky's Node.js JS environment.

```
spooky.then([{
   clickMore: clickMore
}, function(){
    clickMore.call(spooky); // <- spooky is not defined here
}]);
```

Please have another look at what the Introduction wiki page says about [JavaScript Environments](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/wiki/Introduction#javascript-environments) and [the fact that they are isolated](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS/wiki/Introduction#javascript-environments-are-isolated).

Comment: You didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Sure I did. The provided code will not work. I explained why and pointed to the relevant documentation.

Comment: Well, according to the update in the question, the provided code didn't work. I understand that you wanted to point out what the error is, but this does not provide a solution to this problem. This rather shows what the root of the problem is.